# How to solve celerybeat is down: no pid file found?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have followed instructions from https://pythad.github.io/articles/2016-12/how-to-run-celery-as-a-daemon-in-production
It works pretty well for celeryd, however when starting celerybeat it says pid file not found.

I've used this tutorial on my previous projects and it did fine for both celeryd and celerybeat. The difference of this project only is all project files including the django project are owned by root. I fail at finding more details about the issue.

Comment: Can you post some piece of code or stack trace?

Comment: I doesn't give me any stack trace and I don't know how to make it do so. All it says is "starting celery" when running the script and "celery is down, no pid file was found" when checking the status via `/etc/init.d/celerybeat` status command.

Answer (score 8):

You also need to change permissions of the log directories that celery writes to:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/
sudo chown root:root /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/
```

Comment: I have already done that. I solved my issue right now but it is more kind of a hack than a solution. I put CELERY_BIN="python3 manage.py shell" instead of "/usr/local/bin/celery" and instead of init.d I've used systemd.

Comment: Saved the day!, After adding permissions,  have to start the celery service again...